# Java Mac Xbootclasspath

Tags: java, macos

On any tutorial I go to, for example [this](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2010/02/replacing-and-patching-java-application-and-core-classes/), to use Xbootclasspath it's:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/class:/path/to/rt.jar class
```

The problem is that Mac Java doesn't have rt.jar. I tried doing this with classes.jar, but it didn't work. What's a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the path to classes.jar used a symlinked folder. I used the actual folder instead, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When using the latest oracle java on mac (homebrew) the rt.jar file is present.

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```